# Classification with no classifiers in the training data

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have data of news over the period of years and I want to train the data such that whenever I give it a testing news it returns me its the industry to which the news is related for example 'manufacturing' or 'finance'. It can be done using a classification algorithm but unfortunately I do not have the classifiers to train the data as well. My data looks like this:

```
ID   |    News      
1    |    News1      
2    |    News2      
3    |    News3
```

If the data would have been in the following form then I could apply classification algorithms to classify the industry:

```
ID   |    News  | Industry Related to 
1    |    News1 |     Manufacturing
2    |    News2 |     Finance 
3    |    News3 |     e-commerce
```

But you know news apis does provide industry related to news. How can I train my model in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to achieve this, and each has advantages and disadvantages. The problem you describe isn't an easy one.

I can't give a general and correct answer to this question, as it depends heavily on what you are trying to achieve.

What you are trying to do is called [unsupervised learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsupervised_learning)
. Generally the Google-term you could use is "classify unlabeled data".

The Wikipedia-article of this topic has a very good overview of techniques that you may use. Since machine-learning problems often aren't clear-cut and algorithms chosen very a lot per project (size of the dataset, processing-power, cost of misclassification, ...) no one will be able to give you a general perfect answer without actually knowing your data and problem in detail.

Personally from just reading your post my first approach would be to use a clustering-algorithm (like k-means-clustering (see the Wikipedia-article, I cannot post more than two links), using the [cosine-similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) of the texts) to generate different clusters of News, and then look through these clusters, label them manually, and use the result as training data - or automatically generate labels using tf*idf (see the Wikipedia-article, I cannot post more than two links)

However, the results of this may be very good, very bad or anything in between.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have studied basics of unsupervised learning and cosine distance similarity between documents in fact LSH as well but didn't get that far to be able to think that I can apply it here :)

Answer (score 1):

Recent advances in zero-shot and few-shot learning can let you build your classifier with little (100 - 200 training data) or no training data at all. Your classifier still retains all the benefits of a supervised classifier and gives you the control to decide your categories.

I have built one such system and you can try out the [demo](https://www.paralleldots.com/custom-classifier) on your own categories and data to see the system in action.